# How come `Effect` seals only two in-flows, instead of all the flows?

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

Here is the diagram of `Effect` provided in the official tutorial of `pipes` package.

```
 type Effect = Proxy X () () X

  Upstream | Downstream
     +---------+
     |         |
 X  <==       <== ()
     |         |
 () ==>       ==> X
     |    |    |
     +----|----+
          v
          r
```

Since `Effect` doesn't have any flow of data, I was expecting it to be just `Proxy X X X X`, sealing all flows. But instead, it allows the two in-flows. Is there a particular reason for that? If I just write what a `Effect` normally does, with signature `Proxy X X X X`, it can pass the compiler perfectly fine:

```
myMonad :: Proxy X X X X IO ()
myMonad = do
    a <- lift $ getLine
    lift $ print a
    return ()
```

Why can't we `run` something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You **can** run `myMonad` from your example, by just taking the existing definition of `runEffect` and generalizing its type somewhat:

```
import Pipes (lift)
import Pipes.Core (closed)
import Pipes.Internal

type Effect' a b = Proxy X a b X

-- Definition copied straight from Pipes.Core, type generalized to Effect'
runEffect' :: Monad m => Effect' a b m r -> m r
runEffect' = go
  where
    go p = case p of
        Request v _ -> closed v
        Respond v _ -> closed v
        M       m   -> m >>= go
        Pure    r   -> return r

eff :: Effect' X X IO ()
eff = do
    a <- lift $ getLine
    lift $ print a
    return ()

main :: IO ()
main = runEffect' eff
```